# MySQL - Is there a `on select` attribute available?

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL DB rows are selected like this

```
SELECT * FROM application WHERE id = '.$id.'
```

The table has a bool `state` field which reflects if the row is currently `in use` by a user.

After fetching a row I update this field with true (1).
Is there a way in MySQL, something like an `on select` arttribute, to update such a field automatically when selected ? Or is there another clever way to automate a function doing this when preparing a `SELECT` statement ?

Comment: trigger ??? Pleas describe more ...

Comment: There is no way. You need to perform 1 select statement and 1 update statement (inside a transaction), or place those 2 statements in a stored procedure which you call from your code. (The suggestion of triggers cannot be used, they do not apply to select statements.

Comment: When does a row stop being 'in use'? What are the implications of a row being 'used'?

Comment: A row is `in use` when a user selects it. Then the `state` field is set to 1.  The next user may fetch it but is not able to make an update (readonly). The row stops beeing used when the previous user, who selected the row, set the `state` field of the row back to 0

Comment: Sounds like you need locking reads.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: hey thats a good hint. I am not a mySQL professional and still learning. It has such a huge scope, great.

Comment: A little bit of theory, but might just be a good piece of information, unless already seen before - [ACID Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) of Databases. It'd explain why `Locking` is hence one of the mechanisms to ensure the preservation of these properties.